# Using pdo query() and custom getValue() on same database object?

Tags: php, oop, pdo

```
class connector {
  private static $db;
  function __construct() {
    $this->db = null;
    $this->connect();
  }
  private function connect() {
    $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8','user','pass');
  }
  public static function getDB() {
    if (!isset(self::$db)) {
      self::$db = new connector();
    }
    return self::$db;
  }
```

**EDITED**

```
  // this was my original function, I had reduced it for less space. my deepest regrets, I won't do it again.
  public function getValue($sql,$val='') {
    if ($val != '') {
      $data = $this->db->prepare($sql);
      $data->execute($val);
      return $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    }
    else {
      return $this->db->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    }
```

using this class I can easily use the pdo database object from anywhere, with custom functions.

```
$db = connector::getDB();

// var_dump()
db:object(connector)#1 (1) {
  ["db":"connector":private]=>
  object(PDO)#2 (0) {
  }
}

$db->getValue('SELECT foo FROM bar'); //succeeds

$db->query('SELECT foo FROM bar'));
// throws
// Fatal error:  Call to undefined method connector::query()
```

if I return the actual object param instead of the whole object:

```
return self::$db->db;
db:object(PDO)#2 (0) {
}
```

the queries exchange roles

```
$db->getValue('SELECT foo FROM bar');
// throws
// Fatal error:  Call to undefined method connector::getValue()

$db->query('SELECT foo FROM bar')); //succeeds
```

**How can I have both with the same object**, effectively using `$db->query()` and `$db->getValue()` in the same script.

Comment: `class connector extends pdo`?

Comment: hrmm.. I think `PDO` is the built-in php data object class.. it throws `SQLSTATE[00000]: No error: PDO constructor was not called` when I `extends PDO`

Comment: You're accessing the static property `$db` in non-static ways. That is not going to work

Comment: In the construct, call: `parent::__construct()`. Also see some [example here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php#107451) on extending classes.

Comment: Please don't extend `PDO`. There is nothing you could add to make it any better than it already is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `getValue()` method lacks one essential feature - **support for prepared statements**. Without ability to run dynamical queries it's value is close to nothing.

Second, if you are using a singleton anyway - then there is no need for the extra method to get an instance - nowadays singleton can do it just by itself.

[What about this one?](https://github.com/colshrapnel/thebestpdowrapper) I wrote it to make PDO usage less wordy, utilizing neat method chaining. `DB` static class is *already* a PDO instance, without the need to instantiate it with extra call. As a result, you can run any PDO command just anywhere:

```
DB::query('SELECT foo FROM bar LIMIT 1')->fetchColumn();
```

It takes little more space than yours but at least it is giving you access to full PDO syntax, including support for prepared statements

```
DB::prepare('SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE id=?')->execite([$id])->fetchColumn();
```

as well as all other fetch methods

```
DB::query('SELECT foo FROM bar')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Comment: I have just found one potential bug, so, please re-download the code, if you decided to use it. Removed one non-essential feature, not related to the topic in question.

Comment: Is there something I really do not understand, or does the class myPdoStatement prevents the use of bindValue or bindParam? since `$data` defaults to an empty array, using `execute()` without argument after binding a value executes the statement with an empty array, throwing an error?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier it doesn't prevent anything nor adds any functionality. Everything you can do is exactly the same what you can do with original PDO. Yes, you can *avoid* manual binding with PDO, passing array with values directly to execute - PDO will bind them internally. No, empty array doesn't raise an error

Answer (score 1):

Your re-use of the variable `$db` for both the static instance of the `connector` singleton and the private `PDO` member variable is confusing. Without shying away from your singleton approach, maybe try using some better variable names, eg

```
class connector {
    private static $instance = null;
    private $db;

    private function __construct() {
        $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8','user','pass', [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        ]);
    }

    private function __clone() {} // because singletons should not be cloneable

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$instance == null) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * @return PDO
     */
    public function getDb() {
        return $this->db;
    }

    public function getValue($sql) {
        // as is
    }
}
```

Now, if you must run `PDO::query`, you can do so via the `getDb` method...

```
$db = connector::getInstance();
$db->getValue('SELECT foo FROM bar');
$db->getDb()->query('SELECT foo FROM bar');
```

Comment: this even leads me to think about having both in separate variables. I like that sound.